# JSreact render issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner coder diving into ReactJS with webpack. Taking a course on my own liberty on Udemy, but I cannot figure out why my code isn't working because the code appears exactly the same as the videos ive followed.

The question simply is, why isn't the video detail file rendering properly?

Though I have 5 component files, I will only include the parent index.js and the child video_detail.js as the problem I have is with those 2 files only.

index.js file

```js
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/searchbar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';
const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyAi1CzVpifuFUDVQf3dzrTu3mwJDP2n8r8';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  //Do i expect this component to play any type of state? aka pass props
  this.state= { videos: []};
      //  ^proper name can be anything
  YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
// console.log(data);
  this.setState({ videos });
});  // this.setState({videos : vidoos});  
 }
 render (){
 return (
 <div>
  <SearchBar />
  <VideoDetail video={this.state.video[0]} />
  <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} /> 
            
 </div>
  ); 
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_detail.js file

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoDetail = ({video}) => {
 if (!video) {

  return<div>Loading...</div>;
 }


 const videoId = video.id.videoId;
 const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

 return(
  <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
   <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={url}> </iframe>
   </div>
  <div className="details">
  <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
  <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
  </div>
   </div>
 );
};
export default VideoDetail;
```

Additional info : google stephen grider github and the repository will pop up, I am using ReduxSimpleStarter. This will help with answering the above question I hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be videos[0] instead of video[0] ?

Change `<VideoDetail video={this.state.video[0]} />` to

```
<VideoDetail video={this.state.videos[0]} />
```

Comment: I tried this and this solution works. Thanks very much!